# Build different apk with flavors using parse sdk in android studio

Tags: android

I want to build three flavors such as development, prelive and live with different parse application Id.  how to build apk in different flavors to pass application id using parse sdk in android studio?

Comment: Try this:- http://androiddevcorner.blogspot.in/2014/10/building-multiple-apks-inside-android.html